# Can I redistribute my skill points?

Tags: borderlands-2

Uh oh, I already made a decision I regret!  Is there any way I can respec my character?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can reset your skill points at any customization store. The button should be under the the character name setting in the store. Just like in the first Borderlands, there is a small but negligible fee every time you wish to reset your skills.

[image: Borderlands 2 Customization Shop]
[image: Borderlands 2 Re-spec]

Comment: What's the fee like ?

Comment: @PhilippeLavoie Not sure what the math behind it is, but the cost to respec scales with your character's level.