# Collecting all skins and customizations

Tags: borderlands-2

I found several class and vehicle skin upgrades/customizations/unlocks, e.g.:
[image: assassin skin]

Do they carry between games? Do some always drop in the same locations? Do they always appear in the same places or after the same quests? If so, what and where are all of them? What do I need to know to collect the whole list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most customization rewards are for your current class, but you can pick up/activate other classes' customization items. Skin collection progress carries between characters. Activated skins show as "Already Unlocked."

<sup>*This wiki is a work in progress—modify the listings if a skin isn't class-specific.*</sup>

#### Mission rewards

- [Shielded Favors](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shielded_Favors)

  - Sting Like a Bee (Assassin skin)
  - At Arms (Commando skin)
  - Amarillo (Gunzerker skin)
  - [Mellow Yellow](http://images.wikia.com/borderlands/images/7/7d/Shielded_Favors_1.png) (Siren skin)
- [Symbiosis](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Symbiosis)

  - Blast Shield (Assassin head)
  - A Sense of Dread (Gunzerker head)
  - One-Eye Spy (Siren head)
  - Grizzled Veteran (Commando head)
- [Plan B](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Plan_B)

  - SDU Weapon Equip Slot
- No Vacancy

  - Streamlined (Assassin skin)
  - Loud and Proud (Siren skin)
- In Memorium

  - Punk (Assassin head)
  - Bowler Badass (Gunzerker head)
  - Nevermore (Siren head)
- [The Cold Shoulder](http://www.ign.com/wikis/borderlands-2/The_Cold_Shoulder)

  - Salvador SMASH! (Gunzerker skin)
- Statuesque

  - 3ng13 (Assassin head)
  - Top Card (Gunzerker head)

#### Challenge rewards

- "Boom." Level 3 (explosive damage)

  - Torgue Explosiveness (Assassin skin)
- "It's Not Easy Looting Green" Level 3 (get green items)

  - Preying Mantis (Siren skin)
- "Whaddaya Buyin?" Level 3 (Eridium purchases)

  - Green-Eyed Monster (Assassin skin)
  - Greenblood (Siren skin)
- "Open Pandora's Boxes" Level 3 (open lootable objects)

  - Blue Bot (Assassin skin)
- Aggravated Assault Level 3 (assault rifle kills)

#### Misc.

- Moxxi slot machines (get triple 7s)

  - Vladof Sickle (skin, all classes)
  - Tediore Customer Service (skin, all classes)
- Marcus weapons vending machine "Item of the Day"

  - Dahl Elite (Assassin skin)
  - Jakobs Old-Fashioned (Assassin skin)
  - Torgue High Octane (Assassin skin)
  - Bandit Blood and Rust (Gunzerker skin)
  - Hyperion Honor (Gunzerker skin)
  - Tediore Low Price (Siren skin)
- [Vault Veteran Rewards](http://www.trueachievements.com/customimages/008473.jpg) (detecting a *Borderlands 1* save on your console)

  - Vault Veteran: Arachn1d (Assassin head)
  - Vault Veteran: Lancer (Commando head)
  - Vault Veteran: Sledgehammer (Gunzerker head)
  - Vault Veteran: Dr. Crazy (Siren head)
  - Pandoran Legend (all classes skin)
- [Special edition](http://www.co-optimus.com/images/upload/image/2012/borderlands%202%20preorder%20dlc%20full.jpg)

  - Special Edition: F0rg0tten (Assassin head)
  - Special Edition: Snowblind (Commando head)
  - Special Edition: Private Eyes (Gunzerker head)
  - Special Edition: Clean Shave (Siren head)
  - Special Edition: Fired Up (all classes skin)
- Enemy drops (random?)

  - Honey Hive (Bandit Technical skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay)
  - Burst Fire (Assassin skin, found from ship boss in north Southern Shelf)
  - Alabaster (Bandit Technical skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay and Tundra Express)
  - Infrared (Bandit Technical skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay)
  - Volcanic (Commando skin, found in The Dust)
  - Blue Barber (Runner skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay and Tundra Express)
  - Spilled Paint (Runner skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay)
  - Splatter Burst (Runner skin, found in Southern Shelf Bay and Tundra Express)
- Lootable objects (random?)

  - Blood Bank (Runner skin, found in a Bullymong pile right outside Liar's Berg)
  - Sky Runner (Runner skin, found in a Bullymong pile within Liar's Berg)
  - Splatter Burst (Runner Skin, found in a Bullymong pile in Liar's Berg graveyard)
- Don't Remember

  - Root for the Home Team (Gunzerker skin)
  - Woe in the Dark (Gunzerker skin)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the skins/heads you get from challenge rewards are only for the same class you complete them with. I'm guessing you're an assassin, which is why all those rewards are assassin skins. The same goes with "Item of the Day" skins.

Comment: I just found an "Item of the Day" skin that was not for my class, so scratch that. I'm pretty sure that the challenge rewards still apply though - ie. they only give skins for your class.

Comment: Care to add your findings to the wiki?

Answer (score 7):

You can get them from chests,containers,from breakable and destroyable objects,enemy/boss drops,slot machines and they can be found in shops as "Item of the day".You can also get some from quests and challenges.

Yes,they do carry between all characters you have on your profile.

You can also get "Borderlands Veteran" heads and skins for all classes if the game detects a save file from Borderlands 1 on your PC.

Comment: I think enemies drop them too, I've found them laying on the ground after some murder

Comment: Yup i got some from enemies as well,updated my answer.

Comment: On the PC, you can edit some text files to get the bonus rewards from various sources (collector's edition, pre-order, BL1 save existence, etc.). See the guide at http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/borderlands2cheatscodes.html#.UFuPoo2PW30

Comment: Also note, I don't know how frequent this is, but I've actually had a Skag dig one up in front of me. It looked like it was scavenging for food (or maybe trying to get to me as I was standing some 30ft above it), it started to dig and boom, some skin popped up.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't seem to have any rep and can't just append this as a comment, I'm making it its own answer.  I'm pretty sure you can get them from the same places ChrisHateZ mentioned: shops, chests, and breakables.

You can, however, also get them as quest rewards.  For example, the side quest "[Shielded Favors](http://www.ign.com/wikis/borderlands-2/Shielded_Favors)" (from Sir Hammerlock) tends to reward you with skins/heads as well.  And, of course, there are also the skins for having a Borderlands 1 save and for having bought any of the special editions.

Answer (score 1):

> Do they carry between games?

Yes.

While playing Commando, I got a GunZerker customization.  I used it promptly and then was able to customize my GunZerker in a different game.

Comment: I didn't knew it was possible to get customization item for other class,I'm playing Gunzerker and so far Iv'e found good amount of customization items and they were all for my class.

Comment: Well, I started GunZerker first, then played some Commando... game might be tracking what characters I have and only giving me customizations for those characters.  My advice would be - go ahead and create all the characters you might be interested in - then the game can give you customizations for all of those.

Comment: I just recently got the assasins customization on my Gunzerker,so it seems that you can get customization items for other classes after all but not as often as the ones for your class.

Answer (score 0):

I completed some challenge as an Assassin (I forget which, but I believe it was for dealing damage to slagged enemied), and I received a Gunzerker Maliwan skin. Weird. Also, I've never even made a Gunzerker.

The challenge reward for killing either 300 or 500 Loaders (challenge level 3) is the Hyperion skin.

Comment: Hi A_player, this is more a question and answer site. Not a forum where you tell your experiences in the game. So do you have any information that answers the questions Sean is asking? Or do you have anything to add to the answers others have given?