# Which challenges unlock Skins?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Collecting all skins and customizations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84838/collecting-all-skins-and-customizations)

A small number of challenges unlock Skins for your class type at a certain challenge level; usually level 3 or 5.

Which challenge levels unlock which skins?

Answer (score 3):

The following 33 challenges grant skins - data is inconsistent/conflicting on which tier of each challenge grants it, so they are presented without levels, but presented *with* the objective of each challenge. Note that two different challenges grant the same skin (Pink Pandacorn). Note that some challenges must first be unlocked by gaining levels in other, previous challenges (usually associated with the same weapon).

- "...To Pay the Bills" (Kills earned with Action Skill)
- "Knee Deep in Brass" (Rounds fired)
- "Marauder? I Hardly Knew 'Er" (Marauders killed)
- "Longshot" (Kills with Sniper Rifles)
- "EXPLOOOOOSIONS!" (Kills with MIRV Grenades)
- "Not Full of Monkeys" (Kills with barrel damage of all elements)
- "Rocket and Roll" (Kills with Rocket Launchers)
- "Crouching Tiger, Hidden Assault Rifle" (Kills with Assault Rifles **while crouching**)
- "Hail of Bullets" (Kills with SMGs)
- "Open Pandora's Boxes" (Lootable containers opened, including chests)
- "Shotgun!" (Kills with Shotguns)
- "Aggravated Assault" (Kills with Assault Rifles)
- "Super Novas" (Kills with Nova Shields)
- "Whaddaya Buyin'?" (Purchase items with Eridium)
- "Fisticuffs!" (Kills with melee attacks)
- "Load and Lock" (Loaders killed)
- "Eviscerated" (One-Hit Sniper Rifle kills on Shielded enemies)
- "Quick Draw" (Pistol kills earned shortly after aiming down sight)
- "Badass Bingo" (Second Winds earned from Badass kills)
- "Slag-Licked" (Total amount of bonus damage dealt due to Slag element)
- "Just Want to Set the World On Fire" (Total amount of Fire-elemental damage dealt)
- "Pull the Pin!" (Kills with Grenades)
- "The Killer" (Kills with Pistols)
- "Nothing Rhymes with Orange" (Number of legendary items looted) OR "JEEEENKINSSSSS!!!!" (Kills of a rare Loot Midget) (both grant the same skin)
- "It's Not Easy Looting Green" (Number of green items looted)
- "For the Hoard!" (Money accumulated)
- "Boomerbang" (Kills with Tediore weapon reloads)
- "Boom." (Kills with Explosive-elemental damage)
- "Catch-A-Rocket!" (**Direct Hit** kills with Rocket Launchers)
- "This is No Time for Lazy!" (Co-Op Revivifications)
- "Ammo Eater" (Bullets absorbed with an Absorb Shield)
- "Blue Sparks" (Vehicle kills while power-sliding)

([Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AhFsHQLashxcdG0zUmRFQXdia3ZHWHpFdlNPS1haT0E&toomany=true) - Google Docs Spreadsheet; [Originating Gearbox Forums Thread](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=151494))